# Trigger url after success of order placed in magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.8.1 and I am working on sms integration. I am trying to trigger a api url after clicking on placed order button. But as I new on magento I don't know where I put that url. After finding, I get these code of button

```
  <div class="clear"></div>
    <button style="float:left" onclick="oscPlaceOrder(this);" 
      id="onestepcheckout-button-place-order" type="button" 
      title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" 
      class="btn-proceed-checkout onestepcheckout-btn-checkout onestepcheckout-place">
    <span>
       <span><?php echo $this->__('Place order now') ?></span>
    </span>
   </button>      
  </div>
```

now here is one function `oscPlaceOrder`:

```js
function oscPlaceOrder(element) {
        var validator = new Validation('one-step-checkout-form');
        var form = $('one-step-checkout-form');
        if (validator.validate()) {
            if (($('p_method_hosted_pro') && $('p_method_hosted_pro').checked) || ($('p_method_payflow_advanced') && $('p_method_payflow_advanced').checked)) {
                $('onestepcheckout-place-order-loading').show();
                $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').removeClassName('onestepcheckout-btn-checkout');
                $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').addClassName('place-order-loader');
                $('ajaxcart-load-ajax').show();
                checkAjax('<?php echo $this->getUrl('onestepcheckout/index/saveOrderPro', array('_secure' => true)); ?>');
            } else {
                if (checkpayment()) {
                    element.disabled = true;
                    var already_placing_order = true;
                    disable_payment();
                    $('onestepcheckout-place-order-loading').show();
                    $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').removeClassName('onestepcheckout-btn-checkout');
                    $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').addClassName('place-order-loader');
                    //$('one-step-checkout-form').submit();
                    var options = document.getElementsByName('payment[method]');
                    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        if ($(options[i].id).checked) {
                            if (options[i].id.indexOf("tco") != -1) {
                                var params = Form.serialize('one-step-checkout-form');
                                var request = new Ajax.Request(
                                '<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() . 'isAjax/tco'; ?>',
                                {
                                    method: 'post',
                                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                                        if (transport.status == 200) {
                                            if (transport.responseText.isJSON) {
                                                var response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                                                $('onestepcheckout-place-order-loading').style.display = 'none';
                                                $('checkout-' + response.update_section.name + '-load').update(response.update_section.html);
                                                $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').removeAttribute('onclick');
                                                $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').observe('click', formsubmit());
                                                $('onestepcheckout-button-place-order').disabled = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    onFailure: '', //checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                                    parameters: params
                                });
                            } else if (options[i].id.indexOf("wirecard") != -1) {
                                var params = Form.serialize('one-step-checkout-form');
                                var request = new Ajax.Request(
                                '<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() . 'isAjax/wirecard'; ?>',
                                {
                                    method: 'post',
                                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                                        var response = JSON.parse(transport.responseText);
                                        if (response.url) {
                                            window.location.href = response.url;
                                        } else {
                                            var payment_method = $RF(form, 'payment[method]');
                                            var wireparams = {'paymentMethod': payment_method};
                                            url = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() . 'wirecard_checkout_page/processing/wirecard_checkout_pagecheckout/'; ?>';
                                            var wirerequest = new Ajax.Request(
                                            qmoreIsIframe,
                                            {
                                                method: 'get',
                                                parameters: wireparams,
                                                onSuccess: function(innerTransport) {
                                                    if (innerTransport && innerTransport.responseText) {
                                                        try {
                                                            var innerResponse = eval('(' + innerTransport.responseText + ')');
                                                        }
                                                        catch (e) {
                                                            innerResponse = {};
                                                        }
                                                        if (innerResponse.isIframe)
                                                        {
                                                            toggleQMoreIFrame();
                                                            $('qmore-iframe').src = url;
                                                        } else {
                                                            window.location.href = url;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                onFailure: ''
                                            });
                                        }
                                    },
                                    onFailure: '', //checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                                    parameters: params
                                });
                            } else {
        if(isUseAmazon() == false){
         $('one-step-checkout-form').submit();
        }
        else{ 
         <?php 
          if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Amazon_Payments')){
           $helperAmz = new Amazon_Payments_Helper_Data();
           if(isset($helperAmz))
           $checkoutUrl = $helperAmz->getCheckoutUrl(false);
          }
         ?>
         window.location.href = "<?php if(isset($checkoutUrl)) echo $checkoutUrl;?>";
        }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function checkAjax(url) {
        var form = $('one-step-checkout-form');
        var payment_method = $RF(form, 'payment[method]');
        var shipping_method = $RF(form, 'shipping_method');
        var parameters = {
            payment: payment_method,
            shipping_method: shipping_method
        }
        get_billing_data(parameters);
        get_shipping_data(parameters);

        if ($('giftmessage-type') && $('giftmessage-type').value != '') {
            parameters[$('giftmessage-type').name] = $('giftmessage-type').value;
        }
        if ($('create_account_checkbox_id') && $('create_account_checkbox_id').checked) {
            parameters['create_account_checkbox'] = 1;
        }
        if ($('gift-message-whole-from') && $('gift-message-whole-from').value != '') {
            parameters[$('gift-message-whole-from').name] = $('gift-message-whole-from').value;
        }
        if ($('gift-message-whole-to') && $('gift-message-whole-to').value != '') {
            parameters[$('gift-message-whole-to').name] = $('gift-message-whole-to').value;
        }
        if ($('gift-message-whole-message') && $('gift-message-whole-message').value != '') {
            parameters[$('gift-message-whole-message').name] = $('gift-message-whole-message').value;
        }
        if ($('billing-address-select') && $('billing-address-select').value != '') {
            parameters[$('billing-address-select').name] = $('billing-address-select').value;
        }
        if ($('shipping-address-select') && $('shipping-address-select').value != '') {
            parameters[$('shipping-address-select').name] = $('shipping-address-select').value;
        }

        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'post',
            evalJS: 'force',
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                // alert(JSON.parse(transport.responseText).url);
                if (JSON.parse(transport.responseText).url == 'null' || JSON.parse(transport.responseText).url == null) {
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.display = 'block';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.top = '15%';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.left = '40%';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.width = '551px';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.height = '400px';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.overflow = 'hidden';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').style.padding = '5px';
                    $('ajaxcart-loading').innerHTML = JSON.parse(transport.responseText).html;
                    $('iframe-warning').style.textAlign = 'left';
                }
                else
                {
                    window.location.href = JSON.parse(transport.responseText).url;
                }
            },
            onFailure: function(transport) {
            },
            parameters: parameters
        });
    }
```

I think I have to put the url in this function, but where and how, I don't understand. So please help me

Comment: You have multiple ajax requests in code shown and next to no information on what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() In your payment module Model and return your url to redirect customer to external page.

An other alternative could be to use the authorize() and trig a curl to the external url.